# Get Background image to FULLY resize with Background

Tags: html, css

Okay what i cant seem to figure out is I want any image no matter what size to fit to the browser window EXACTLY corner to corner as a background image.  what usually happens is the BG image corners seem to overflow to where they cant be seen. like the browser uses the middle of the image sort of but i need it exact! ANy help, would  be greatly apprectiated!!!!....

heres the page link http://www.bxwebdesign.com/stack/index.htm  and

http://www.bxwebdesign.com/stack/style.css

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `background-size: 100% 100%;`. This will fill the element exactly corner to corner with your image.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size for documentation on this CSS property.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, its not as simple as that..... when you add 100% then 100% all your telling it to do is put 100% width then 100% height but when that is all you put and you dont put something like no-repeat it will just put tons of little images down your page with 100% width and like 10px height it's not as simple as that. I appreciate your input though..

Comment: That's not really true. If you fill, say BODY like I said, then you need to make sure that the BODY element actually is the height of your browser window. That doesn't have anything to do with the background image per se. You can enforce that by adding `html { height: 100%; }` to your CSS. I've made a CodePen that shows an image stretching from corner to corner at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avbObY

Comment: I was already assuming it was under the body element... but that is why you have to be specific...Thanks

Comment: No problem! Hope this works like you want it to. Note in some really old browsers (IE before 9? I'm not exactly sure) `background-size` isn't supported. If you need to support those browser you have to use JavaScript to calculate dimensions and stretch a `<img>` to fill the browser window.